# If $A,B,$ and $C$ are sets, then $A\times(B-C)$ = $(A \times B)$ $-$ $(A \times C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B,$ and $C$ are sets, then $A\times(B-C)$ = $(A \times B)$ $-$ $(A \times C)$.

*Proof.* Observe the following sequence of equalities.

$$\begin{align}
A\times(B-C) &= \{(x,y)\} : (x \in A) \wedge (y \in (B-C))\} \, (\text{Definition of Cartesian Product}) \\
&=\{(x,y) : (x \in A) \wedge \big((y \in B) \wedge (y\notin C)\big)\} \,
 (\text{Definition of } -) \\ 
&=\{(x,y) : (x \in A) \wedge (x \in A) \wedge \big((y \in B) \wedge (y\notin C)\big)\} \, (P=P \wedge P) \\
&=\{(x,y) : \big((x \in A) \wedge (y \in B)\big) \wedge \big((x \in A) \wedge (y\notin C)\big)\} \, (\text{Rearrange}) \\
&=\{(x,y) : \big((x \in A) \wedge (y \in B)\big) \wedge \big((x \in A) \wedge (y\notin C)\big)\} \, (\text{Definition of }\cap) \\
\end{align}$$

I'm stuck on the last part -- $(x \in A) \wedge (y\notin C)$ translates to $(A-C)$ but I need it to be $(A \times C)$. I can't quite figure out how to reach that.

Comment: From $(x \in A \land y \in B) \land (x \in A \land y \notin C)$ we may "distill" : $[(x,y) \in A \times B] \land [(x,y) \notin A \times C]$.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you make a proof with logic, don't use the equality symbol, we use the implication symbol because the implication symbol is defined for the  logic propositions.

So, i'm gona show first that $(A \times B) -(A\times C) \subseteq A \times (B-C)$

Let $(x,y)\in ((A \times B) -(A\times C))
\implies (x,y)\in (A \times B) \land (x,y) \not \in (A \times C)$

$\implies (x\in A \land y\in B) \land \lnot (x\in A \land y\in C) 
\implies (x\in A \land y\in B) \land (x\not \in A \lor y \not \in C)$

$\implies (x \in A \land y \in B \land x\not \in A) \lor (x \in A \land y \in B \land x\not \in C) $

By TTP:

$\implies (x \in A \land y \in B \land x\not \in C) \implies x\in A \land y \in(B-C)$

$\implies (x,y)\in(A \times (B-C))$

Now, i'm gonna show that $A \times (B-C) \subseteq (A \times B) -(A\times C)$

Let $(x,y)\in (A \times (B-C))
\implies x\in A \land y\in (B-C)
\implies x\in A \land (y\in B \land y \not \in C)$

$\implies (x\in A \land y\in B \land y \not \in C) \lor (x \in A \land y \in B \land x\not \in A)$

$\implies (x\in A \land y\in B) \land (x\not \in A \lor y \not \in C)$

$\implies (x\in A \land y\in B) \land \lnot (x\in A \land y\in C)
\implies (x,y)\in (A \times B) \land (x,y) \not \in (A \times C)$

$\implies (x,y)\in ((A \times B) -(A\times C))$

Then, $(A \times B) -(A\times C) = A \times (B-C) \blacksquare$

Comment: This particular line:
$⟹ (x \in A \wedge y \in B \wedge y \notin C ) \vee  (x \in A \wedge y \in B \wedge x \notin A) $ \\


Can you explain how to get $(x \notin A)$ and $(x \in A)$ both in there? I don't quite understand the reason for that! 
thanks!

Comment: @SaadKhan I use the addition property of propositional logic:
$p \implies p \lor q$

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with how OP used the equality symbol or their general approach to writing their proof.