# Prove that $A \times (B -C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to use set theory to prove that: 
$$A \times (B -C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$$

I tried using direct proof but I couldn't prove it that way.

How should it be done?

Comment: See also: [If $A,B,$ and $C$ are sets, then $A\times(B-C)$ = $(A \times B)$ $-$ $(A \times C)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1997439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(x,y)\in ((A \times B) -(A\times C))&\iff (x,y)\in (A \times B) \land (x,y) \not \in (A \times C)
\\
&\iff(x\in A \land y\in B) \land (x\not \in A \lor y \not \in C)
\\
&\iff (x \in A \land y \in B \land x\not \in A) \lor (x \in A \land y \in B \land y\not \in C)
\\
&\iff 0\lor (x \in A \land y \in B \land y\not \in C)
\\
&\iff  x \in A \land y \in B \land y\not \in C
\\
&
\iff  x \in A \land y \in (B - C)
\\
&\iff (x,y)\in A\times(B-C)
\end{align}
Hence
$$
(A \times B) -(A\times C)=A\times(B-C)
$$

Answer (score 1):

To show two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal, you should show $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$.

Let $x\in A\times (B-C)$. Then $x=(a,y)$, where $a\in A$ and $y\in B-C$. What does that tell us about the element $x$? Can you deduce that it must be an element of $(A\times B)-(A\times C)$? If so, that shows $A\times(B-C)\subset(A\times B)-(A\times C)$.

Similarly, let $x\in(A\times B)-(A\times C)$. Then $x\in A\times B$, so $x=(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Moreover, $x$ is not an element of $A\times C$. Again, what can you deduce about $x$? Show that it is an element of $A\times (B-C)$, and this shows that $(A\times B)-(A\times C)\subset A\times (B-C)$.

After showing these two, equality follows.