# Proving of set identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGyEO.jpg)
[2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyJQw.jpg)

How can one prove the following identity:

$$B\times(C\cap A) = B\times(C∪A) \setminus B\times(C\bigtriangleup A)$$
I tried it so many times but there's nothing.

There are three photos of one of my attempt. The solution progress may not be absolutely clear - sorry for this. 
I can rewrite, if you need.

Thanks a lot for any help!

---

Okey. Thanks to @User1006 I prove the identity.

1. By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012354/410122) I prove that $B×(C∪A)-B×(C△A)=B×((C∪A)-(C△A))$.

   $(x,y) ∈ B × (C ∪ A) - B × (C △ A) ⟺ (x,y) ∈ B × (C ∪ A) ∧ (x,y) ∉ B × (C △ A) ⟺
       (x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C ∪ A)) ∧ (x ∉ B ∨ y ∉ (C △ A)) ⟺ (x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C ∪ A) ∧  x ∉ B) ∨ (x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C ∪ A) ∧ y ∉ (C △ A)) ⟺ 0 ∨ (x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C ∪ A) ∧ y ∉ (C △ A)) ⟺ x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C ∪ A) ∧ y ∉ (C △ A) ⟺ x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C∪A)-(C△A) ⟺ (x,y) ∈ B×((C∪A)-(C△A))$
2. Now return to both parts of the identity. We can see that:
   1) For the right part of the identity $(x,y) ∈ B×(C∪A)-B×(C△A)⟺ (x,y) ∈ B×((C∪A)-(C△A))⟺ x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C∪A)-(C△A)$
   2) For the left part of the identity $(x,y) ∈ B×(C∩A)⟺ x ∈ B ∧ y ∈ (C∩A)$
3. So our task now is to prove that $C∩A=C∪A−C△A$
   The approval is in [User1006's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2114166/410122) below.

Comment: What is $\oplus$? Symmetric difference?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, exactly.

Comment: As of now you've gotten 4 downvotes. It is _most likely_ because you haven't expanded anything on "I tried it so many times but there's nothing." If you edit your question and _tell_ us one or two things you tried, and exactly what made it not work, preferably in as much detail as possible, this question would've been much better recieved.

Comment: Are you able to demonstrate the single-component identity $C \cap A = (C \cup A) \setminus (C \oplus A)$?

Comment: All images are here : http://dropmefiles.com/sbobj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prove that
$$
C\cap A=C\cup A -C\bigtriangleup A
$$
(We use the standard symbol $\bigtriangleup $ for Symmetric difference.). We use the fact that
$$
C\bigtriangleup A = (C-A) \cup(A-C)=(C\cap A^c) \cup(A\cap C^c)
$$
The proof is as follows:
\begin{align}
C\cup A -C\bigtriangleup A &= C\cup A -((C\cap A^c) \cup(A\cap C^c))
\\
&=(C\cup A) \cap ((C\cap A^c)^c \cap(A\cap C^c)^c)
\\
&=(C\cup A) \cap ((C^c\cap A^c) \cup(C^c\cap C)\cup(A\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap C))
\\
&=(C\cup A) \cap ((C^c\cap A^c) \cup(A\cap C))
\\
&=((C\cup A) \cap (C^c\cap A^c)) \cup((C\cup A) \cap (A\cap C))
\\
&=((C \cap (C^c\cap A^c))\cup( A \cap (C^c\cap A^c)))\cup(A \cap C)
\\
&=(((C \cap C^c)\cap A^c)\cup( (A \cap A^c)\cap C^c))\cup(A \cap C)
\\
&=\varnothing\cup(A \cap C)
\\
&=C \cap A
\end{align}
Then by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012303/prove-that-a-times-b-c-a-times-b-a-times-c/2012354#2012354), it follows 
$$
B\times(C\cap A) = B\times(C∪A) -B\times(C\bigtriangleup A)
$$