# Proof of $A\times(B-C)=(A\times B)-(A\times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any three sets $A,B,C$ I have to prove $A\times(B-C)=(A\times B)-(A\times C)$.

My book shows the following proof-

> Let,arbitrary $(a,b)\in A\times(B-C)$
>
> $\implies a\in A$ and $\color{blue}{b\in(B-C)}$
>
> $\implies a\in A$ and $(b\in B$ and $b\not\in C)$
>
> $\implies (a\in A$ and $\color{red}{b\in B})$ and $(a\in A$ and $b\not\in C)$
>
> $\implies(a,b)\in(A\times B)$ and $(a,b)\notin(A\times C)$
>
> $\implies(a,b)\in(A\times B)-(A\times C)$.

Now my question is in the part marked red we assume $b\in(B-C)$ which means $b\in B$ and $b\notin C$.But in the red part we say $b\in B$ which means we include the whole set $B$ without excluding the intersection with $C$ part.

Now does these two things not contradict each other?I have a doubt whether this proof is correct.

Edit-No reason why my post as closed as duplicate.I didn't want the proof.I specifically had difficulty with a particular logic.So no point redirecting my question to another proof without explaining my difficulty specifically.I already have that proof in my book.

Comment: We reach the line in red by noting that we can distribute $\land$ over $\land$, or in this case, we can use replication : $\iff a\in A$ and $(b\in B$ and $b\not\in C)$ we also have $a \in A \land a \in A \land b \in B \land b \notin C$

>$\iff  (a\in A$ and $\color{red}{b\in B})$ and $(a\in A)$ and $(b\notin C)$.

Comment: @amWhy I think the OP understands the Distribution ... the problem that OP has is understanding why we can just 'drop' the requirement that $b \not \in C$ in the first half of the resulting statement. That is, to the OP it seems like the first half ($a \in B$ and $b \in B$) 'opens the door' for the possibility that $b \in C$, and that doesn't look right to the OP. I think it is an understandable legitimate worry ... and an important confusion/misunderstanding that really needs to be cleared up in order for the OP to understand the logic; not just for this argument, but for many more to come.

Comment: It isn't dropped.  It is only a rearrangement (associativity) across "$\land$".  I'm quite sure that the OP can understand that $1+1 =2 \land 2+2 = 4 \land 2+1 \neq 0.$ means $(1+1 = 2 \land 2+2 = 4) \land (1+1 = 2 \land 2+1\neq 0)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $A \times (B -C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012303/prove-that-a-times-b-c-a-times-b-a-times-c)

Comment: Possibile duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997439/if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-then-a-timesb-c-a-times-b-a-times

Comment: @amWhy Is 1+1=(2 and 2)+2=4 valid logically?...Mathematically 1+1 is not equal to 4...

Comment: I have retracted [my duplicate close vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/807908), since this question seems to be about specific step in a specific proof. (Probably adding ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag would make this even more clear.) I will add the the post has already been closed and then reopened,
 see the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2267378/revisions) and the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2267378/timeline).

Comment: i too had a hard time with this rd proof!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is fine.  By saying that $b \in B$ we are not making any claims whether or not $b$ is in $C$ or not.  But given that $b \in B - C$, it is definitely true that $b \in B$.

Think about it this way. Since $b \in B - C$, we know two things: $b \in B$ and $b \not \in C$.  What logically follows? It logically follows that $b \in B$. That's what the $\Rightarrow$ indicates.

Put differently: the claim $b \in B$ is equivalent to the claim $b \in B$ and either $b \in C$ or $b \not \in C$.  And that claim logically follows from $b \in B$ and $b \not \in C$.

Put differently yet: from the claim that 'It rains and today is Friday', we can infer the claim 'it rains'.  The fact that the latter claim says nothing about today being Friday or not does not take anything away from that logical consequence.

Comment: We are not making any claims but if I say $b\in B$ there is no harm in assuming that there may be a case where $b\in B\cap C$ because we are not saying anything about $C$.And in that case our later statement violates our previous assumption.

Comment: @tatan  That's (partly) right: given $b \in B$ by itself it *may* be true that $b \in C$.  But it *may* also be the case that $b \not \in C$.  So what we are really saying is: '$b$ is definitely in $B$, and it is either true that $b \in C$ or  $b \not \in C$' . And that *whole* statement is true whenever $b \in B - C$.  So it does logically follow from $b \in B - C$, and the claim  '$b$ is definitely in $B$, and it is either true that $b \in C$ or  $b \not \in C$' does *not* violate the claim $b \in B - C$. In fact, it logically follows from it.

Comment: Ok...I have seen your example...but I am not satisfied because raining and donuts tasting delicious are exclusive events (Mathematically they are disjoint)...Even if it is raining or not raining donuts will always be delicious...so the intersection part is missing in this example...and in your second comment how do you say "b may or may not be in C"..when we say $b\in B-C$ we assume definitely that $b$ is **not** in C...or is using **may** correct?

Comment: @tatan LOL!  Yes, donuts are *always* delicious, bad example! :)  But yes, I think the issue is maybe with the word 'may': if $b \in B - C$, then it is indeed not true that $b$ 'may' be in $C$.  OK, so how about this: when we say $b \in B$, we say "$b$ is definitely in $B$ ... whether $b$ is in $C$ we just don't know'. Alternatively we could say: 'In addition to $b \in B$, it is either true that $b \in C$ or it is true that $b \not \in C$'. Now, does that claim *follow* from the claim ' $b$ is in $B$ and $b$ is not in $C$?  Yes, given $b \not in C$, it follows that $b \in C$ or $b \not \in C$

Comment: @Bram28  I hope you have seen my comment, below the question, to you, re: my  one sarcastic comment to you.  As I said there, I apologize for having written that one-liner addressed  to you.  I see now it seems to have been deleted, and rightly so.  Carry on!

Comment: @amWhy  No worries!!  And you keep up the good work as well!

Comment: Bram28 : $\ddot\smile$.

Answer (score 1):

For the marked part you can simply notice that $p\land (q\land r) \Leftrightarrow (p\land q) \land (p\land r)$ is a tautology.

Now substitute $p\equiv (a\in A)$, $q\equiv(b\in B)$ and $r\equiv(b\notin C)$.

Comment: I did not understand the substitution part...can you explain in detail that part?

Comment: You can simply replace all occurrence of $p$ by $(a\in A)$, all occurrences of $q$ by $(b\in B)$ and all occurrences of $r$ by $(b\notin C)$.